# Hint function based on AI moves

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

i am making a game similiar to [Greedy Spiders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=v2mPzh1Xgio#t=142). Briefly said, it is a turn-based game in which there is one or more spiders that are trying to get to the flies to eat them. User's task is to prevent this by cutting a small part from the web in order to free the fly or trap the spider. There is a hint function that shows how to complete the level and free the flies or trap the spiders with the least possible cuts(moves).

I am using A* algorithm to find the shortest path to one of the flies. The algorithm is still not very intelligent, since it finds only the shortest path and does not take into account user's cut.

What I am wondering is how to implement the hint function. What i am thinking of right now is to use a game tree and value each outcomes and choose the best one but I am not sure if this is the best aproach.

What would you recommend for implementing such a function?

PS. I am not trying to copy the app. I want to do something similiar with my own effort so i can get better in problem solving. I want an idea, not a solution...

Comment: So you're trying to copy someone else's app, and rather than copying it on your own efforts, you're trying to get SO to tell you how to do it?

Comment: There will probably be relatively few possibilities for any game that fits on screen. I would just try them all and pick the best.

Comment: Hey dude, I am not asking for implementation or a pseudo-code... Just an idea..

Comment: A question that's not asking for code probably doesn't belong here. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess.

1. In each turn, use A* with all spiders to find the shortest path to the nearest fly for all of them. Somehow store all edges in some ordered data structure for each shortest path for each spider. If a spider has several paths available that share the shortest path length, store all of them. e.g. if a spider has 3 paths available to 3 different flies and all of those paths have length 2, store all of them.
2. "Sort" the paths found in step 1 by path length. Find the shortest among them (those with the minimum length). Let's call these the *shortest shortest paths*.
3. Among all these shortest shortest paths, try to find an edge that is *most* common (highest frequency) among all the paths. Tell the player to cut that specific edge if one exists. If no such "common" edge exists, tell the player to cut the last edge on one of the shortest paths since this will give the greatest chance of freeing one or more flies at once.

I have no rigid proof that this works. It just seems to be an optimal thing to do as a player.

The idea of finding "common edges" between multiple shortest paths came to mind as a way to complete several important objectives in one turn like blocking off several spiders at once (or multiple paths of a single spider at once). There may be more advanced algorithms to do this particular thing. Otherwise, if no "common edges" exist (i.e. all edges have frequency == 1) the optimal strategy seems to be to slowly cut off edges around the flies that are in the most imminent danger one by one.

Comment: For those who are interested the best way to find the least possible moves is to try all possible combinations of cuts and tools,because the frequency is not a guarantee for an optimal solution as my experience shows. The problem is with the algorithm runtime, which forced me to preload the hints in a xml file.